# P2P network on windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am trying to connect two windows phone emulators without router to form p2p network, is there any solution to connect them with access point without router and internet. and can be a possibility of using IP address of emulator.
answer plz

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge no it is not possible in Mango - but is in WP8. You could however use a wireless network to perform create a UDP multicast socket and and then "connect" to one another that way.

Have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2010/03/29/windows-phone-7-platformer-starter-kit-for-xna-studio-4-0.aspx it's got some pretty good pointers.

Comment: ohh thank you, i hope it would help me... keep on posting if you find something new thank you